# Implicit String cloning

Tags: rust

In C++, we can do this:

```cpp
std::string ar[2] = {std::string("hello"), std::string("world")};
std::string hello = ar[0];
std::string world = ar[1];
```

and `hello` and `world` end up being new strings. I think this is because `=operator` is implemented like a `clone()` in Rust.

In Rust, this would look like this:

```rust
let ar = vec![String::from("hello"), String::from("world")]
let hello = ar[0].clone();
let world = ar[1].clone();
```

which gets pretty repetitive very quickly.

Is it possible to make `=` clone the object instead which seems like the natural behavior?

Comment: This is likely to make other Rust developers who need to read or maintain your code unhappy with you. It's convention that implicit copies happen only when it's cheap, and it's not cheap for strings. Thus, it's _intentional_ that code that's potentially slow is verbose about that fact.

Comment: Also, not just cheap, but side-effect-free, especially. cc @CharlesDuffy

Comment: The official rust docs has more details and rational for copy and clone: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: No. In Rust, the assignment operator has move semantics unless the type implements the `Copy` trait.

`String` does not implement the `Copy` trait, but it does implement the `Clone` trait (which is why we can use `clone()`). But why is that?

This is an intentional choice by the language designers. Types that cannot be copied via a simple bitwise copy (`String` is an example, which contains a buffer allocated on the heap) are not allowed to implement the `Copy` trait. The language designers wanted it to be obvious to programmers which types can be "cheaply" copied with a bitwise copy vs types that are more expensive to copy.